# How facebook team uses "custom parameters sent" in the facebook pixels?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

I recently checked airbnb and once I applied filters on the website, it fired Facebook pixel with all the information in custom parameters.

[image]

How is this done i.e. how can facebook show specific ads to people who have viewed certain page on our website? After this was fired I started getting, relevant suggestions when I accessed facebook through same browser. Does this work only when the user is logged into facebook from same browser?

Is it something like facebook will associate this pixel fired with already logged in facebook user on that browser? And if the same user comes to facebook from any other device, he/she would be shown ads based on that pixel?

Comment: Yes, of course that’s how it works ...

Comment: but isn't it being too optimistic that user would be logged in to facebook before accessing other websites firing pixel?

Comment: No, I bet that is the case for the great majority of users ... And even if they are not logged into Facebook _now_, Facebook will still be able to associate data gathered now with the user that logs into Facebook at a later point.

Comment: How do they do it? do we have any document as to how this all works i.e. mapping tracking pixels fired with facebook customer-id? I want to understand this process but unable to get any good source to read.

Comment: what about apps? many people would be using airbnb app and facebook mobile? and other set would be using airbnb mobile and facebook as app only? and they would not be signing in with facebook login in airbnb.